# Serial port and checkboxes updating

Tags: c#, checkbox, serial-port

in my app' i'm recieving data from serial port and save them into two *bool* arrays.
And depends on these array i'm setting checkboxes. But checkboxes are not updating only when i change the tabs....

Here's how i'm doin' it(maybe there's better way how to do it)

```
private void comboBoxCommunication_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort.IsOpen)
  {
    recieveThread.Abort();
        serialPort.Close();               
  }
  ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)comboBoxCommunication.SelectedItem;
  portCommunication = cbi.Content.ToString();
  serialPort.PortName = portCommunication;
  try
  {
    serialPort.Open();
    recieveThread = new Thread(dataRecieving);
        prijmiThread.Start();                                
    checkBoxI1.IsChecked = vstupy[0] ? true : false;
    checkBoxI2.IsChecked = inputs[1] ? true : false;
    checkBoxI3.IsChecked = inputs[2] ? true : false;
    checkBoxQ2.IsChecked = outputs[3] ? true : false;                                           
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error, MessageBoxResult.OK);
    }
}

private void dataRecieving()
{ 
    if (serialPort.IsOpen)
  {                    
    int i = serialPort.ReadChar();
    if (i == 'A')
    {
        inputs[0] = true;
    }
        else if (i == 'a')
        {
        inputs[0] = false;
    }
    if (i == 'B')
    {
        inputs[1] = true;
    }
    else if (i == 'b')
    {
        inputs[1] = false;
    }
    if (i == 'C')
    {
        inputs[2] = true;
    }
    else if (i == 'c')
    {
        inputs[2] = false;
    }
    if (i == 'D')
    {
        outputs[0] = true;
    }
    else if (i == 'd')
    {
        outputs[0] = false;
    }                        
  }           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are tying to launch a thread that checks the serial port and then have your GUI update in near-real time to changes that come across the serial thread you probably need to do several things.

1. I would raise an event from the serial reading code when a checkbox changes state
2. The GUI could subscribe to this event **BUT** you have to be aware of cross threading. That is you can't let the handler of the event directly update the GUI element owned by a separate thread.
3. So in your event handler you need to invoke the update via the owning thread.

I wrote up a [blog entry](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2011/02/cross-threading-revisited.html) once on an idiom for handling cross threading on Winform apps.

I'm also not sure how your inputs array is defined, but in general it's not a good idea for two threads to be accessing shared data without some type of control mechanism. If your array is based on a data type that does atomic read/writes it might be OK but typically you want to consider what happens if one thread is in the middle of a non-atomic write when another thread either reads or writes the same data. Lots of material abounds on thread safety that you probably want to become familiar with.

Comment: To add a note: checkboxes are not refreshing because you are creating a new thread, and the object that it read from the serial port has still the same value, when you try to change the checkboxes.